# Javascript/HTML URL input convert to Hyperlink

Tags: javascript

I am working in ServiceNow using a catalog request UI macro so I cannot call a PHP file.  I want to have users enter an URL into an input field and automatically convert that to a hyperlink without hitting submit (basically when user leaves field).

I tried to put this together using javascript but I'm finding that I am having trouble with the code. The input field isn't even appearing on the page

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<j:jelly trim="false" xmlns:j="jelly:core" xmlns:g="glide" xmlns:j2="null" xmlns:g2="null">
<script>
<input type="text" id="myAwesomeIdName"></input>
    var val = document.getElementById('myAwesomeIdName').value;
    <a href="&val;&" target="_blank">Link</a>
    </script>
</j:jelly>
```

Comment: why do you think input field is not appearing?

Answer (score 2):

One thing i noticed was your

```
<input type="text" id="myAwesomeIdName"></input>
```

is inside the script tags. Try moving it up a line so it is not inside (script).

btw I would have suggested this via a comment, as it is not a complete answer to your question but may assist, but could not because SO will not permit to comment as I have only 41 reputation. Hope I have not upset anyone. Mods if you are able to change this to a comment, or suggest a better way, please feel free.

Comment: It is actually a complete answer! One thing I would add is that the input tag is a self-closing tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can add event listener on input field of your choice e.g. enter or just on change. Get the value and add it to DOM or what ever you want to do with it. If you have something else leme know I will update answer.

```js
const input = document.querySelector('input');
const log = document.getElementById('log');

input.addEventListener('change', updateValue);

function updateValue(e) {
  const yourLink = e.target.value
  const mydiv = document.getElementById("log");
  const aTag = document.createElement('a');
  aTag.setAttribute('href', yourLink);
  aTag.textContent = "link text";
  mydiv.appendChild(aTag)

}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter some text" name="name" />
<div id="log"></div>
```